# What is Order Statistics and ith smallest?

Tags: algorithm, statistics, divide-and-conquer

I have an Algorithm course this semester. Everything is fine until I reached the lecture about Order Statistics.

Here is the first slide of that lecture:

```
Order Statistics
Select the ith smallest of n elements (the
element with rank i).
• i = 1: minimum;
• i = n: maximum;
• i = ⎣(n+1)/2⎦ or ⎡(n+1)/2⎤: median.
Naive algorithm: Sort and index ith element.
Worst-case running time = Θ(n lg n) + Θ(1)
= Θ(n lg n)
```

I cannot understand what are the following:

What is **Order Statistics**?

What does it mean on **the ith smallest of n eleents**? please I need an example to know what is "ith"!!

Any simple explanation about these?

All I know is that this is related to Divide and Conquer, because the next slide is about it :).

Comment: For anyone who finds this in the future, I think this blog post that I wrote might be useful: https://hampuswessman.se/2022/01/order-statistics-computation/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[*"Order statistics"*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic) is a fancy name for "K-th element of an N-element sequence sorted in ascending order". The rest of the slide simply illustrates the idea, explaining that 1-order statistics is the smallest element in a sequence, n-order statistics is the largest element, `n/2` order statistics is the *median*, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

it order statistic is the same as the ith smallest element in an array. For example lets say we have an array A[Size] ={ 3,4,-3,-2,0, 1,10,2,14} and we want the element that corresponds to the 4th. Order statistic then we our function or program will return the value 1.  The algorithm for this utilizes a random partition and recursive calls to the random selection function.

The pseudo code is as follows:

```
 RSelect( Array[], p,r, i)

 if p == r
      return A[p]
 q = RandomPartition(Array[],p,r)
 k = q - p + 1
 if i == k // case that the pivot is the answer 
 return Array[q]

 else if i<k
     return RSelect(Array,p, q-1,i)
 else
     return RSelect(Array, q+1, r, i-k)
```

The algorithm is a divide an conquer algorithm that uses recursion to break up the problem by choosing a random pivot which is done in the random partition function to assist in partitioning the array and throw out values that are either greater than or less than the pivot depending on whether the ith Order statistic is greater than or less than the pivot. For example if the it order statistic is less than the pivot it will discard values greater than the pivot.  because the pivot value returned in the Partition function is in it's proper place.

Comment: Hi Caltor, thanks for your input.  The R_select Algorithm a divide and conquer algorithm is used to find the it Order statistic in O(n).  This could also be achieved by first sorting the array in O(nlogn) time using MergeSort or Quick Sort and just choosing k element where k corresponds to the desired ith-Order Statistic corresponding to the input Array.